# reference or pointer notation with boost::ptr_vector

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, c++11

```
//this returns a boost::ptr_vector<Ordre>     
auto& vec = ptf.listeOrdre().liste();

auto it = std::find_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(),
      [message](Ordre& ordre){return ordre.id() == message->id();}
  );

if( it == vec.end())
{
   return;
}

Ordre& ordre = *it;
```

I have a doubt concerning the "&"  or "*" I should use on the lambda parameter and the last line of code.

Is anyone see something wrong ?

I have a crash in production and I suspect this code

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you pass Message to the Lambda by reference?

Comment: It wouldn't compile at all if ptr_vector returned pointers instead of references. - Perhaps `liste()` returns a reference to a local variable?

Comment: @mark:  I don't know. Why do you think i should pass Message by referenec ?

Comment: @visitor: no it's a field of a class declared on the heap

Comment: @Guillaume07 sorry, if message is a bald pointer what you are doing is fine, if it is a shared pointer capturing it by reference is more efficient.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code.  But since you're using C++11, you might consider replacing `boost::ptr_vector<Ordre>` with `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Ordre>>`.  The advantage of the latter is that it is now standard, and thus you will have a wider audience to help you with questions like this.  The former is basically a work-around for the lack of functionality of the latter prior to C++11.  If you did this, then your accesses into the `vector` would need to use pointer syntax, as opposed to the reference syntax you're currently using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line looks correct.

One possible error may be with `ptf.listeOrdre()`.  If it returns a value, it will be copied.  then `vec` will have a reference to a temporary object.

The parameter to the lambda should be `const&`, but I doubt that is the problem.

Other than that, there is nothing wrong with this snippet of code.

Comment: If `ptf.listeOrdre()` returns a value, then `auto& vec = ptf.listeOrdre().liste();` would fail to compile, as it's illegal to bind a non-const lvalue reference to a temporary.

Comment: @ildjarn.  You're confused.  If `liste()` returned a value the compiler would complain.  But you're allowed to call non-const functions on a temporary.  Which is what would happen if `listOrdre()` returned a value.  see here: [ideone.com/gpUNA](http://ideone.com/gpUNA)

Comment: You're right, I misread. What I meant to say is that if `ptf.listeOrdre().liste()` returns by value, then `auto& vec = ptf.listeOrdre().liste();` would fail to compile; but of course, you were talking about `ptf.listeOrdre()`, not `ptf.listeOrdre().liste()`. Sorry for the noise. :-]